# Identifying and rendering robots

Tags: php, mobile, web-crawler

We have some filter to requisition crawlers, or there should be no difference between robot and rendering in browsers?
A request robots should be considered as a common access via browser?

I read that the robot has google web version and mobile version. 
We need to identify the mobile robot is to display the content as if it were a mobile phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell a robot what it can and cannot access from a file called `robots.txt` in your domains root directory.

Have you taken a read of this?

```
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
```

Its explaining how to allow/disallow robots from certain areas of your site.

**Example:**

To exclude all robots from part of the server

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /junk/
```

Comment: thanks for the link ... I interpret differently when the mobile crawler google or not?

Comment: Yeh google mobile is `Googlebot-Mobile` normal google is `Googlebot` link info here: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1061943

Comment: another note, it's a bad idea to put disallow: /some-super-secret-dir/ in your robots.txt file. lots of nefarious spiders go looking for hidden files this way. just saying!